# Simplification of $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{4n+\sqrt{n}} + 2\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: limits

Can somebody explain how pass to this : $\sqrt{n} / \left(\sqrt{4n+\sqrt{n}} + 2*\sqrt{n}\right)$

to this :
$1 \big/ \left(2 + 2\sqrt{1+ \frac{\sqrt{n}}{4n}}\right)$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks you Donald Splutterwit for formating my post.

Comment: What happens when you divide both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: I have put in some dollars & backslashes ... can you get the close bracket in the right place ?

Comment: Can i put image link ?

Comment: Sure post the image ... i will put it in an eqnarray for you.

Comment: When i divide by $\sqrt{n}\, i obtain : 
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n+\sqrt{n}} + 2\sqrt{n}

Comment: Multiply top & bottom by $1/\sqrt{n}$ and then a little tickering with the denominator ... easy ? ... put your equations in between dollars, not percentages!

Comment: I don't speak english very well, i'l try to put a picture.

Comment: I understood  my mistake, thank you mzp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{n} }{ \sqrt{4n+\sqrt{n}} + 2\sqrt{n}}
=&\;\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}} }{ \frac{\sqrt{4n+\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{n}} + 2\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}}\\[2ex]
=&\;\frac{1 }{ \sqrt{\frac{4n+\sqrt{n}}{n}} + 2}\\[2ex]
=&\;\frac{1 }{ \sqrt{4+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}} + 2}\\[2ex]
=&\;\frac{1 }{ \sqrt{4\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4n}\right)} + 2}\\[2ex]
=&\;\frac{1 }{ 2\sqrt{1+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4n}} + 2}\\[2ex]
=&\;\frac{1}{2 + 2\sqrt{1+ \frac{\sqrt{n}}{4n}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Line 3
Can i say that : n grow more faster than sqrt(n) then limit when n -> +inf = 0  ?

Comment: So it's false to say sqrt(n) / n = 0 when n -> + inf ?

Comment: I checked the graph of sqrt(n) / n and when n is very big , lim = 0 not 1 ?

Comment: It is correct to say that. I am just saying that the argument is clearer if you notice that $\sqrt{n}/n=1/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: My fault i din't readed correctly, but do you pass to sqrt(n) /n to 1/sqrt(n) ?

Comment: Divide up and down by $\sqrt{n}$.